# Entity and form design in bpms

Tags: formbuilder, business-process-management

I am working on a bpms software, I wanted to know how to create an entity and design a form from it and bind these two together.
in asp.core project

I want to be able to make the model dynamically and a form can be designed from it and connected to the database